Raising a Numpy Array to a large power
I am using Numpy to raise a 2 X 2 array (matrix), with positive elements, to an integer power. But if I use a high enough power, I get negative values in the result:
A = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 0]])
B = np.linalg.matrix_power(A, 46)
print(B)

[[-1323752223  1836311903]
 [ 1836311903  1134903170]]

I expected that the numbers in the result should remain positive and keep increasing as I use larger powers.
Why do I get this result instead?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before asking more questions, please read [ask] and the formatting help, in order to understand how to format code properly in the question and to get a general sense of how we want questions to be phrased.

A = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 0]], dtype="int64") or A = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 0]], dtype="float64") allow you to perform the computations.

A.astype(object) uses python ints and can grow indefinately.  Math on object dtype arrays is somewhat hit-or-mis, but works for this calculation.  You didn't mention the purpose of this matrix, but I suspect you came across a method of calculating  fibonacci numbers.
